# What tool do I use to remove this aerator?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

[image: found this tool on the internet, should i buy?][image: photo of my sink aerator]

This is the photo of my sink aerator, i have been searching on the internet but have no idea what tool should i use to remove it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Likely, the end (about 1 or 2 cm thick) just screws on.  Use a rubber band or rubber jar-opener to get a better grip, if need be, to unscrew it.

Comment: Most of us come equipped with 10 tools that are perfect for this task: Fingers.

Answer (score 0):

Spray it with 30% Vinegar to remove calk build up.

Or use a cup with vinegar and submerge it in it for a while.

It should unscrew with ease using fingers.

If needed, use rubber jar opener.